# Missing label on Drupal 5 CCK single on/off checkbox

Tags: drupal, cck

I'm creating a form using the Content Construction Kit (CCK) in Drupal5.

I've added several singe on/off checkboxes but their associated labels are not being displayed.  Help text is displayed underneath the checkboxes but this is not the desired behavior.  To me the expected behavior is that the *label* would appear beside the checkboxes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the [answer](http://drupal.org/node/152892#comment-571201):

It turns out to be functionality provided by the CCK, but it's counterintuitive.

For single on/off checkboxes, drupal will use the *on* label specified in the *allowed values* field:

```
0
1|This is my label
```